# javascript prototype var is undefined, but I'm not sure why.

Tags: javascript

I thought I was "getting it" with javascript and then I run into something like this.  I don't know why the value for __sfcont is undefined.

```
var __container = "It contains ";

function myObject() {
  var temp = 'temp';
}

myObject.prototype = {
  constructor: myObject,
  searchingFor: {
    __sfcont: "a div block ",
    label: this.__sfcont + "and a label.",
    dropdown: this.__sfcont + "and a dropdown."
  }
};

var myObj = new myObject();

console.log(myObj.searchingFor.label);
```

The expected result from this would be `It contains a div block and a label.`  But I'm getting `undefinedand a label.`

Comment: Try testing with `label: this.toString()` and see what you get.

Comment: You aren't assigning `__container` anywhere.

Comment: It can be confusing because you can typically trace the meaning of this by tracing your context up to the nearest parent scope. I think the eye looks up to the nearest curly brace to find the nearest parent scope, but in this case the curly braces are being used to declare an object literal, not a scope.

Comment: @sdgluck  Ah, yes. an oversight. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the time of `this.__sfcont + "and a label.",` execution, `this` is not what you expect. It is not `searchingFor` that has not been constructed yet, but the context in which `myObject.prototype = { ... }` is executing. That context does not have `__sfcont` property.

Make `label` (and `dropdown` too) a method:

```
label: function() { this.__sfcont + "and a label."; },
...

console.log(myObj.searchingFor.label());
```

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks. And as sdgluck mention, I forgot to use __container in my example code.  So now I have `sfcont: __container + "a div block",` and `label: function () { return this.__sfcont + "and a label."; },`  The expected result is then achieved.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access object properties while initialization. You can define variable and then reuse it:

```
var __sfcont = "a div block ";
myObject.prototype = {
  constructor: myObject,
  searchingFor: {
    __sfcont: __sfcont,
    label: __sfcont + "and a label.",
    dropdown: __sfcont + "and a dropdown."
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a getter

```
myObject.prototype = {
  constructor: myObject,
  searchingFor: {
    __sfcont: "a div block ",
    get label() {
      return this.__sfcont + "and a label"
    }
  }
};

console.log(myObject.searchingFor.label)
```